# Gmail: How to forward/export all my existing mails to another mail account?

Tags: email, gmail, export

I don't know whether this is asked already or not but I could not find the solution.

I want all my **existing** mails to be forwarded to another mail (yahoo/gmail) account. There are some thousands of mails. What is the best way to forward/export all preferably in an organised way (keeping the inbox, sent mails etc. and the labels).

I found some restrictions like if a user sends to more than some hundred recipients, or if most (not sure how much) out of the recipients are invalid/non-existent mail ids then gmail temporarily blocks the mail id without any notice (something similar).
 I don't want this to happen.

Comment: As per the Super User [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) questions about web services and websites are off topic. However, you could try asking on the [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange beta site instead, they should be able to help.

Comment: Ok here is a related question http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/347/how-can-i-import-mail-from-one-gmail-account-to-another-preserving-my-label-stru